# Where to store app data?

Tags: android, android-studio, saving-data

I'm building relatively simple app/game which consists of tasks and subtasks. The user's progression should be saved. User also have small amount of settings.

For now app doesn't connect to external services, but in the future the goal is to use Facebook or something similar for user registration and add a feature to share progressinon/accomplishment with other users.

I'm new in app development and I don't know which data storage method to choose. If I've not mistaken there's key-value sets, saving in a file and database option.

To get things done fast and maybe even release the v. 1.0 I'd like to go with the most simple solution. So, I'd like to know is there a downside to choose the key-value or saving in a file option and how difficult is it to switch to database-based saving? Or should I just use the database from the start?

I salute You for taking the time to answer this!

-Timo

Comment: primarily opinion-based ... did you check "Storage Options" topic in official android guides?

Comment: `Shared Preferences` are good option for you.

Comment: Thanks AJay! I'll try that.

Comment: Plenty of storage options to choose from: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
Simples SharedPrefs, files, sqlite..

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based question because I asked about the possible problems that I might face in the future by choosing the wrong method. Apparently this forum is not the place to ask general type questions and only strict coding questions are allowed :(

Comment: It actually is opinion-based. There is no one straight guideline on how to save user progress data in a game. Shared Preferences is something that may be too simple for you. And as for Database, there are plenty to choose from. SQLite, Firebase, RealmIO. Each would have their own pros and cons and you'd really have to select based on your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend for you the SharedPreferences. This is an in Android simple class, that stores you data in Key-Value sets.

Here is the code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

This initialize your SharedPreferences. If you want to write/change a value, do this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("KEY_TO_VALUE", 123);
editor.commit();
```

You also can put in there other types of values, but than you need to call `putString` or `putBoolean` or even other types.

To read the value do this:

```
int a = prefs.getInt("KEY_TO_VALUE", 0);
```

This code need like always your parameter your Key and a the second parameter a default value.

Another tip for you is, that if you want to use this in a normal app with an easy UI there is something called PreferenceScreen.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a go.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). For mor complex things you need to use SQLite(built-in) or some ORMs like [Realm](https://realm.io/) or [GreenDao](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/). For online score sharing you need to use one of above mentioned and a server. Facebook let you store only one integer per user which is sometimes not enough and also for storing that integer you need to ask extra permission from user(publish_actions). Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! These are useful tps.